# How to backup a AmazonAWS website (Laravel) to AmazonAWS S3 bucket?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

It would strike me as something rather mundane, but so far I cannot find any reference to how I can backup my Amazon AWS hosted application to my AWS S3 Bucket automatically on a regular basis?

Long story short, I have a AWS VPS with MySQL and WordPress installed and now am looking to do weekly/monthly backups of the site, including the DB. This seems to be possible via a WP plugin called "Updatedraft Plus" which allows for backups to be created and pushed over to S3 buckets, but given that this is a rather simple feature, I am quite sure that Amazon must have a solution for this already, I just cant seem to figure out how to do it.

I run both a WP site and a Laravel application if that matters, so could rely on either to assist with the backup.

Thanks for any advice on this.

Comment: Doesn't AWS automatically look after backing up your instance ready for an instant restart?

Comment: I thought so too, but so far I havent found anything about this. AWS Glacier only allows for vaults to be setup but doesnt do the backing-up, Lightsail has a snapshot feature which only backs-up configuration. I am at a loss.